# Get date value in Pacific Standard Time for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

We would like today's date in Pacific Standard Time in Ruby using the Date class (because we use Mongo and Mongo can't handle the Time class). How can we do this?

Essentially, we want to guarantee that `today = Date.to_mongo Date.today` always returns today's date in PST.

We're on Rails 3.12 and using MongoMapper.

Thanks.

Comment: Which ODM are you using? (Mongoid / MongoMapper)

Comment: We're using MongoMapper

Answer (score 2):

This is a little low-level (in that you manipulate the offset, rather than declare 'PST' somewhere), but might do the trick:

```
d = DateTime.now.new_offset('-08:00').to_date
```

Not sure if you have daylight-saving time, which would make things more complicated?

You *could* put this snippet into `Date.today`, but that would over-ride machine settings, so I'd recommend something more specific like

```
class Date
  def self.today_pst
    DateTime.now.new_offset('-08:00').to_date
  end
end

today = Date.to_mongo Date.today_pst
```

Also, warning, if you convert back to Time or DateTime, the zone is not preserved.